# Zend Framework: How to intentionally throw a 404 error?

Tags: zend-framework, http-status-code-404

I would like to intentionally cause a 404 error within one of the controllers in my Zend Framework application. How can I do this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

A redirect to a 404 would be:

```
throw new Zend_Controller_Action_Exception('Your message here', 404);
```

Or without Exception:

```
$this->_response->clearBody();
$this->_response->clearHeaders();
$this->_response->setHttpResponseCode(404);
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that you could set the code for that exception. The API doc seems to point to it being for internal use only, though.

Comment: Well, I use it all the time with custom routes.. For example `example.com/:module/:controller/:random`. In the controller I check if random exists, otherwise I throw and Exception with a 404 and it works :-)

Comment: Hmm, this isn't working for me. The controller keeps marching on normally. Do I need to do anything else after this?

Comment: can I return array as you returned string in exception?

Answer (score 1):

You can always set the response code manually, without throwing any exceptions.

```
$this->_response->clearBody();
$this->_response->clearHeaders();
$this->_response->setHttpResponseCode(404);
```